# Laravel 5: Get the default value of my select option with onChange event using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<select>` that has 4 `<option>`s: `Straight Line`, `Double Declining Balance`, `Unit of Production`, and `Sum of Years Digits`. I'm having a hard time in the edit part because when I put the `onChange` event on my `<select>`, my default value doesn't show.

Here's what I tried: I used a `v-if` to set the default selected value of my `<select>`.

**Edit.vue**

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group" v-if="asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id == 0">
        <label>Asset Depreciation Method <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control asset-depreciation" name="edit_asset_depreciation" required="required" @change="assetDepreciation" v-model="asset_depreciation">
            <option value="0" selected>Straight Line</option>
            <option value="1">Double Declining Balance</option>
            <option value="2">Units of Production</option>
            <option value="3">Sum of Years Digits</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" v-else-if="asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id == 1">
        <label>Asset Depreciation Method <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control asset-depreciation" name="edit_asset_depreciation" required="required" @change="assetDepreciation" v-model="asset_depreciation">
            <option value="0">Straight Line</option>
            <option value="1" selected>Double Declining Balance</option>
            <option value="2">Units of Production</option>
            <option value="3">Sum of Years Digits</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" v-else-if="asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id == 2">
        <label>Asset Depreciation Method <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control asset-depreciation" name="edit_asset_depreciation" required="required" @change="assetDepreciation" v-model="asset_depreciation">
            <option value="0">Straight Line</option>
            <option value="1">Double Declining Balance</option>
            <option value="2" selected>Units of Production</option>
            <option value="3">Sum of Years Digits</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" v-else>
        <label>Asset Depreciation Method <span class="required-field">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control asset-depreciation" name="edit_asset_depreciation" required="required" @change="assetDepreciation" v-model="asset_depreciation">
            <option value="0">Straight Line</option>
            <option value="1">Double Declining Balance</option>
            <option value="2">Units of Production</option>
            <option value="3" selected>Sum of Years Digits</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    // In my add, this will appear then the asset depreciation mtehod is Unit of Production, thats why I used the if statement,
    <div class="form-group periods" v-if="asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id == 2">
        <label>Period</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="periods" v-bind:value="asset_edit.period">
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I set the default value of my `<select>` while also triggering a `change` event on the `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

The `<select>`'s value is already bound to `v-model`, so you don't need to conditionally render the `<option>`s in that manner. Instead, set the `v-model` variable to the value of the desired default `<option>` value, and the data binding will automatically select the `<option>`. The `v-model` could be set upon changes to `asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id`, using a [watcher](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to monitor the changes:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    asset_edit: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      asset_depreciation: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    "asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id": {
      handler(value) {
        this.asset_depreciation = value
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming the only reason for the default setting to also cause a `change`-event is to invoke `assetDepreciation()`, you could just call it inside the watcher:

```js
watch: {
  "asset_edit.asset_depreciation_id": {
    handler(value) {
      this.asset_depreciation = value
      this.assetDepreciation(value) // invoke the select's change-handler
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Setting default selected option]